# Create 1-bit Comparator with mux

Tags: logic, comparator, circuit, mux

I want to make a 1-bit comparator with 2x1 mux or 4x1.
I have made this 2x1.
I am stuck in this situation.

1 bit comparator with 3 2x1 mux:
[image: 1 bit comparator with 3 2x1 mux]

2x1 mux:
[image: 2x1 mux]

I have to use only the 2x1 mux or 4x1, NOT gates as well as stable volt power (0 or 1).

What do I do wrong?